# Load right image in android webview with orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout, webview

I have an android image where I am loading an image from the drawable dir as follows:

```
public void loadSplashInWebview() {
    mSpeechWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_res/drawable/", "<img src=\"splash.png\" height=\"98%\" width=\"100%\"/>", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
}
```

I call the above method in `onCreate` and this looks right in portrait mode but in landscape, the image looks shifted to the left. I have another image with the correct size in the `drawable-land` dir but the webview won't automatically switch to that in landscape mode.

As a test, I tried setting the url to `file:///android_res/drawable-land/` in `onConfigurationChanged` but then android throws an error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.project.example.R$drawable-land" on path: DexPathList
```

Is there a way to make the webview load the correct image without depending on configuration changes (I do not want to have to override `onConfigurationChanged` and would like it to handle the switch in `onCreate` itself) ?

**Edit:** I can override `onConfigurationChanged` if there is no other way. The real issue seems to be that webview can't seem to get to `drawable-land`.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to handle config changes then you can remove

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

for that activity from manifest.

This will allow system to recall `onCreate` every time orientation changes.

Now you will be able to load image according to orientation in your `WebView`.

Hope this helps.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: I don't want to do that either :(. Worst case, I can override onConfigurationChanged but the real issue is that webview cant seem to get to 'drawable-land.'

Comment: The you will need to keep both files in drawable folder. And switch with the file by getting the orientation manually. I guess drawable-land will not be generated. System will only switch the resources in drawable reference  if you allow it to do so.